# php & mysql - Fetch users last paid month and compare it with the current month to send email

Tags: php, mysql, email, payment

This is a school project and I need to send emails to those who haven't paied the current month bill.

My table looks like this:

```
id   id_profile     code       month(m-Y)    value
1         1       XXXXXXXX      10-2016       50
2         1       XXXXXXXX      09-2016       50
3         1       XXXXXXXX      11-2016       50
4         2       XXXXXXXX      09-2016       50
5         2       XXXXXXXX      08-2016       50
6         2       XXXXXXXX      10-2016       50
```

I'm using INNER JOIN to fetch the users email so that's ok.
What I need is to get the highest paid month because the user will be able to pay next months or the oldest payments can be rejected and have to pay them again.

My current query:

```
SELECT t1.month, t2.email FROM incomes AS t1 INNER JOIN profiles AS t2 ON t1.id_profile = t2.id
```

So, fetch the higher paid month, and compare it with the current month to see if the user has a debt and send the user a single email to remind them they have to pay

I was thinking in a while loop or something. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why is your `month` column that format? This would be much simpler if you used a standard date format - `YYYY-MM-DD`, even if you didn't need the day value and just set it by default to `01`. Then you would be able to do this in your query, and not need a php loop to evaluate string values.

Comment: I didn't think it was that important. So, assuming that the month field is in your suggested format, how the query would be? Thank you and I'm still learning, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do it without changing the date format (as @sean suggested) on the month field,

I used the `MAX` function along with `date_format` and `str_to_date` to fetch the highest paid month, also `GROUP BY` to get one row per user, and used some php to compare the month & year with current date to send the email to the users that owe the current month.

So the MYSQL query would be like this:

```
SELECT date_format(max(str_to_date(t1.month,'%m-%Y')),'%m-%Y') AS debt, t2.email
FROM incomes AS t1 INNER JOIN profiles AS t2 ON t1.id_profile = t2.id 
GROUP BY t1.id_profile
```

The php would be something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){ // To excute with every row
    foreach ($row as $campo => $valor){ 
        $$campo = $valor;
    }

    if (date("m-Y", strtotime('01-'.$debt)) < date('m-Y')) {
        //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }

}
```

Since the month field isn't a standar date I had to convert the string.

I hope this helps someone.